# when using boost::filtering_ostream, why does it not have a sync() function?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream

According to [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html), the following should compile:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream out;
out.sync();
```

yet mysteriously it doesn't. my vs2010 compiler yells:

```
error C2039: 'sync' : is not a member of 'boost::iostreams::filtering_stream<Mode>'
      with
      [
          Mode=boost::iostreams::output
      ]
```

I'm using boost 1.50.0 but boost.iostreams has not changed since boost 1.46.0

Comment: Well, I can't figure out why, but it appears that `boost::iostreams::detail::chain_client` (the relevant base of the filtering_ostream) no longer has the `sync` method, but only the `strict_sync`.